# poor mans source control zip project files on build

Tags: visual-studio

I am looking for a way to zip a project including all files and have the zip file dated.
has anyone done this and is it possible ?

Comment: Why so humble my friend? Choose a lofty title - "Royal man's Source Control © "

Comment: Which OS are you working on? When should the files be created? Will they be automatically generated (nightly-builds) or are you going to decide on the "when"? Answer some of the questions and you'll get better answers on SO.

Answer (score 1):

Sure, I did this for years using Windows NT.  I created a batch file named `bu.bat` in each project and also a backup directory named `bu`.  The batch file contained

```
pkzip -ex bu/projectprefix%1 *.c *.cpp *.asm *.h *.bat (etc.)
```

and then I would use it by first listing the backup directory to see what the next number to use is and then

```
bu 179
```

`Pkzip` stores the file timestamps into the archive.  `-ex` chooses `x`tra (a higher level) of compression.