# Compress Workspace for archiving App versions

Tags: iphone, compression, backup, versioning

**Now**(6:13pm Jun 1, 2012):  I resign myself to learning git and github so that I can do version control.   I won't need to mail copies of the (compressed) code to myself, but I still don't understand the mechanism after a day of looking at this stuff.

I get the SHA1 concept for uniquely identifying a file, and using the first 2 characters fo the hash as a directory name.  But I'm still confused on the updates, pointers, merge business.

**Previously**: I have multiple versions of programs, so I can regress to an earlier one to solve a problem.

I used to like to compress the one I was using, and send it to myself via email, but today when I did that the compressed version was too small (49 kb instead of 6 mb).  So I guess I am referencing the "workspace" (the extension on the app is ".xcworkspace").

I probably shouldn't waste too much time on this problem, since it is merely a backup, but on the other hand, having the full size is an indication that the whole app is self contained, instead of pointers elsewhere that may be inadvertently changed or destroyed.

Is there any way to "undo" my current version to have all the correct data, or is it really tough?

Answer (score 1):

From personal experience I agree with other commentators that Git is the way to go, or even Mercurial.  The learning curve bends down after a while especially if the needs are modest.

As to the need for a "Poor Man's Version Control", sometimes you do need one.  For example, you work at a employer that does not allow downloading and use of non-corporate software and the centralized VCS is not allowed to be used for Ad Hoc, Experimental, or skunk work.

Related post:  [poor mans source control zip project files on build](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7701573/poor-mans-source-control-zip-project-files-on-build)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how to get back any changes without knowing more about your set up, but I can recommend that you look into a slightly new setup: your email-an-archive-to-yourself system sounds like a poor man's Revision Control System, except worse than poor, because there are plenty of great RCS tools available for free.

I recommend you spend an hour or so and read about `git`. If you learn a few commands you can have a complete change history of your project, and jump back to any point in time you like. (And then change history, creating alternate timelines, become your own grandparent, and cause all sorts of problems/adventures.) Most of the time version control is used in the context of a development team, but it provides a lot of benefit even for a lone wolf.

Comment: I didn't want you to think I'm ignoring your advice. I'm watching:  "Introduction to Git with Scott Chacon of GitHub" [link] http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZDR433b0HJY   and am 23 minutes into 1:22.    It's slow and aimed for people who use other Versioning Control Systems.

Comment: No problem: the advice is free and if you don't like it, I offer a full refund. :-) `git` is a little weird, I resisted it for a long time, but it's one of those things that, once you figure it out, all the weirdness makes perfect sense.

Comment: This might be helpful, it's git from another angle: http://nfarina.com/post/9868516270/git-is-simpler

Comment: OK: I saw the complete Scott Chacon video, and it was above my head, so that I understood about 20% of it.  I couldn't follow how the merges worked, and whether you then had to deal with a specific line of code that differed, or if it substituted the entire "module" for the previous one.  I "sort of" understood where he changed the color to blue, and another change of adding his email, and then doing one or both of them.  But it was incomprehensible after that.  Now, I'll look at the other post "git-is-simpler"

Comment: Sadly, I read [link]http://nfarina.com/post/9868516270/git-is-simpler  "Git Is Simpler Than You Think", which I don't find to be true.  Although I was amused to see that if you do a Google search for “git checkout -- .” you wind up on a page written by the Master: Linus Torvald   [link]http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/v1.7.3/git-checkout.html